# Looking up custom taxonomy IDs by name

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom post type, 'fee', which has a custom taxonomy, 'fee-category'.

I'm trying to look up IDs for items in the taxonomy by name. Should I not be able to get it using `get_term_by()`?

Something like this:
`get_term_by('name', 'Sample Name', 'fee-category')`

I even tried just looking for taxonomies by ID, using IDs I know exist and no luck.

Anyone know which function I should be using?

Perhaps there's something in my code registering the taxonomy? Here it is:

```
  add_action( 'init', 'create_fee_taxonomy' );

  function create_fee_taxonomy() {
    // Add new taxonomy, make it hierarchical (like categories)
    $labels = array(
            'name' => _x( 'Fee Category', 'taxonomy general name' ),
            'singular_name' => _x( 'Fee Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
            'search_items' => __( 'Search Fee Categories' ),
            'all_items' => __( 'All Fee Categories' ),
            'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Fee Category' ),
            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Fee Category:' ),
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Fee Category' ),
            'update_item' => __( 'Update Fee Category' ),
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Fee Category' ),
            'new_item_name' => __( 'New Fee Category Name' ),
            'menu_name' => __( 'Fee Category' ),
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'fee-category', array( 'fee' ), array(
            'public' => true,
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'labels' => $labels,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_admin_column' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
    ) );
}
```

Comment: The function get_term_by returns an object, you could get the ID from the object. `$obj = get_term_by('name', 'Sample Name', 'fee-category'); echo $obj->term_id;`

Comment: That's what I thought, but this `var_dump( get_term_by('name', 'Sample Name', 'fee-category') );` is returning this: `bool(false)` And 'Sample Name' does exist. I also substituted 'id', '12' (which is the id for 'Sample Name') for the first two variables and got the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran a quick test on a site that uses custom taxonomies. The sample code that you used works for me.

I did the following

```
$test_term_by = get_term_by('name', 'Sample Name', 'my-custom-taxonomy');

// note that this produces a "stdclass object", not an array.

echo '<pre>';
print_r($test_term_by);
echo '</pre>';

echo $test_term_by->term_taxonomy_id; // one of the values of our object.
```

Perhaps you want to do some testing with the `get_term_link( $term, $taxonomy )` function, which is a bit more straightforward in it's output, and can be useful for your debugging.

Comment: PS: `bool(false)` is the result I get for terms that don't exist or were deleted.